# Finding the first ancestor in an inheritance tree in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks something like this

```
plant ancestor1 ancestor2 ancestor3 ancestor4 ancestor5
XX     XX1          XX2      XX3      XX4       XX5
YY     YY1          YY2      YY3      YY4
ZY     ZZ1          ZZ2      YY2      YY3       YY4
SS1    SS2          SS3
```

For each plant I want the get the oldest ancestor. Final output should look something like this

```
plant oldest
XX     XX5
XX1    XX5
XX2    XX5
XX3    XX5
XX4    XX5
YY     YY4
YY1    YY4
YY2    YY4
YY3    YY4
ZY     YY4
ZZ1    YY4
ZZ2    YY4
SS1    SS3
SS2    SS3
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df2 = df.ffill(axis=1).melt(id_vars='ancestor5', value_name='plant')
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'ancestor5': 'oldest'}).drop(columns='variable')
df2 = df2[df2['oldest'] != df2['plant']]
print(df2)

   oldest plant
0     XX5    XX
1     YY4    YY
2     YY4    ZY
3     SS3   SS1
4     XX5   XX1
5     YY4   YY1
6     YY4   ZZ1
7     SS3   SS2
8     XX5   XX2
9     YY4   YY2
10    YY4   ZZ2
12    XX5   XX3
13    YY4   YY3
14    YY4   YY2
16    XX5   XX4
18    YY4   YY3
```

Explanation: use melt to transform to a long-form dataframe, but before we can do this, make sure we have one column which always contains the ancestor by using ffill. Later, delete the rows where the values were duplicated by the forward fill.

Comment: Sorry, I got TypeError: drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'

Comment: That's odd. Could you print the output of the line until that part (so `df2.rename(columns={'ancestor5': 'oldest'})`?)

Comment: Oh I got it, I just changed variables to variable

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fast method using numpy isin, repeat, and concatenate along with list comprehensions.  This way also allows for empty ancestor positions to be empty strings or None or any other place holder.

```
df_vals = df.values
# count the number of sub-ancestors in each row
repeats = (~np.isin(df_vals, ['', None])).sum(axis=1) - 1
# find the oldest ancestor in each row
oldest_ancestors = np.array([df_vals[row, col] for row, col in enumerate(repeats)])
# make the oldest column by repeating the each oldest ancestor for each sub-ancestor
oldest = np.repeat(oldest_ancestors, repeats)
# make the plant column by getting all the sub-ancestors from each row and concatenating
plant = np.concatenate([df_vals[row][:col] for row, col in enumerate(repeats)])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'plant': plant, 'oldest': oldest})
```

-

```
print(df2)

   plant oldest
0     XX    XX5
1    XX1    XX5
2    XX2    XX5
3    XX3    XX5
4    XX4    XX5
5     YY    YY4
6    YY1    YY4
7    YY2    YY4
8    YY3    YY4
9     ZY    YY4
10   ZZ1    YY4
11   ZZ2    YY4
12   YY2    YY4
13   YY3    YY4
14   SS1    SS3
15   SS2    SS3
```

Setup dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'plant': ['XX', 'YY', 'ZY', 'SS1'],
                   'ancestor1': ['XX1', 'YY1', 'ZZ1', 'SS2'],
                   'ancestor2': ['XX2', 'YY2', 'ZZ2', 'SS3'],
                   'ancestor3': ['XX3', 'YY3', 'YY2', None],
                   'ancestor4': ['XX4', 'YY4', 'YY3', None],
                   'ancestor5': ['XX5', None, 'YY4', None]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'plant': ['x', 'y','z'], 
                   'ancestor1':['X1','Y1','Z2'],
                   'ancestor2':['X2','','Z2'],
                   'ancestor3':['X3','','']})
df['oldest'] = [list(filter(len,list(df.iloc[i])))[-1] for i in range(len(df))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another go (a bit ugly maybe) at this using list comprehension.

```
dfout = pd.DataFrame([
        (y, x[-1]) for x in [[i for i in ii if i] for ii in df.values] 
        for y in x[:-1]
    ], columns = ['plant', 'oldest']
)
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'plant': ['XX','YY','ZY'],
    'ancestor1': ['XX1','YY1','ZZ1'],
    'ancestor2': ['XX2','YY2',''],
    'ancestor3': ['XX3','','']
})

df = df[['plant','ancestor1','ancestor2','ancestor3']]
dfout = pd.DataFrame([
        (y, x[-1]) for x in [[i for i in ii if i] for ii in df.values] 
        for y in x[:-1]
    ], columns = ['plant', 'oldest']
)
print(dfout)
```

Returns:

```
  plant oldest
0    XX    XX3
1   XX1    XX3
2   XX2    XX3
3    YY    YY2
4   YY1    YY2
5    ZY    ZZ1
```